# Can't record a 1080p video from the iOS Simulator with the Quicktime Player

Tags: quicktime, imovie, xcode-simulator

I am trying to record a video of my iOS game, using Quicktime Player, running the iPhone8Plus Simulator in a portrait mode which is supposed to produce a 1080px1920 video. However, the resolution I got is 750x1334 in iMovie after trying to share it as an App Preview. Please, advise me on what I should do to get the required resolution.

Thank you

Comment: 750x1334 is the resolution of an iPhone 8, not an iPhone 8 Plus. Can you confirm that you've selected the correct simulator?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did.